# How does variable scope work in Hugo for different pages?

Tags: hugo

How does variable scope work in Hugo for for different pages?

I can make a list of post titles on my home page by adding this code to `themes\[theme name]/layouts/_default/list.html`:

```
<ul>
{{ range .Data.Pages.ByPublishDate }}
        <li>
            {{ .Title }}
        </li>
    {{ end }}
</ul>
```

However the same code in a standalone page `content/archive.md` produces nothing. How do I get a standalone page to list entries from the `/post` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `.Data` object is scoped to the content type it is called within. To access different type of content use the `.Site` object on which you can access the `.Pages` object. That object contains all the pages of all content types. Simply filter for the content type you want using the where function, `where .Site.Pages "Type" "post"`.

So your code becomes:

`<ul>
{{ range  (where .Site.Pages.ByPublishDate "Type" "post") }}
        <li>
            {{ .Title }}
        </li>
    {{ end }}
</ul>`